# In Android what you mean by docking state

Tags: android, android-intent, dock

In Intent,there is a constant named `ACTION_DOCK_EVENT`

Added in `API level 5`
Broadcast Action: A sticky broadcast for changes in the physical docking state of the device.

What do you mean by docking state?

Comment: android doc about `dock status` => http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/docking-monitoring.html

Answer (score 2):

Android devices can be docked into several different kinds of dock devices . These include car or home docks and digital versus analog docks. So when a dock of the device is changed then it throws an intent of `ACTION_DOCK_EVENT`

If a device is docked, it can be docked in any one of four different type of dock:

- Car
- Desk
- Low-End (Analog) Desk
- High-End (Digital) Desk

resource [here](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/docking-monitoring.html)

Answer (score 1):

> what do you mean by docking state

Docking state means generally  your charging state,it may be a `car`,`home dock`,`digital` or `analog docks`,Android devices can be docked into several different kinds of docks.

**Determine the Current Docking State**

The `dock-state` details are included as an extra in a sticky broadcast of the `ACTION_DOCK_EVENT` action. Because it's `sticky`, you don't need to register a `BroadcastReceiver`. You can simply call `registerReceiver()` passing in null as the broadcast receiver as shown in the next snippet.

```
IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_DOCK_EVENT);
Intent dockStatus = context.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);
```

Answer (score 0):

The dock-state details are included as an extra in a sticky broadcast of the ACTION_DOCK_EVENT action. Because it's sticky, you don't need to register a BroadcastReceiver. You can simply call registerReceiver() passing in null as the broadcast receiver as shown in the next snippet.

```
        mContext = getApplicationContext();
        IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_DOCK_EVENT);
        Intent dockStatus = registerReceiver(null, ifilter);
```

You can extract the current docking status from the EXTRA_DOCK_STATE extra:

```
        int dockState = (dockStatus == null ?
            Intent.EXTRA_DOCK_STATE_UNDOCKED :
            dockStatus.getIntExtra(Intent.EXTRA_DOCK_STATE, -1));
        boolean isDocked = dockState != Intent.EXTRA_DOCK_STATE_UNDOCKED;
        boolean isCar = dockState == Intent.EXTRA_DOCK_STATE_CAR;
```

Whenever the device is docked or undocked, the ACTION_DOCK_EVENT action is broadcast. To monitor changes in the device's dock-state, simply register a broadcast receiver in your application manifest as shown in the snippet below:
action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_DOCK_EVENT"

Hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should add a bit more explanation in an answer, either as a separate paragraph shortly telling what the code does, or as comments within the code. In other words, "working code" for what purpose, doing what?

Comment: This does not answer the question asked. In Android what do you mean by docking state? This does not require writing codes

Answer (score 0):

From [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-check-if-the-android-device-is-in-dock-state/) post:

> A docking station is a device that is competent in communicating with
> the Android kernel to fire docking-related events and revise the
> docking file state. A docking station can make the system and apps do
> anything that is programmed. One example is showing a different layout
> on the docked state. It may also open a music player app, play music
> automatically on desk mode if it is programmed as such, open a
> map/navigation app in car mode, etc. Dock Mode is different on
> different phones, but it often turns your phone into a desk clock,
> photo slideshow viewer, or music player. You can also set it as a
> speakerphone when you receive calls. The dock is built into
> self-amplified speakers or music boxes, or it is a stand-alone unit
> that connects via USB to a computer, charger, or home theater
> equipment. Some docks use USB for charging and Bluetooth for playing
> music. This mode is a feature that can be detected on some phones,
> including many of the Samsung phones, but is not a feature detect on
> every phone or every version of a phone. For example, Samsung Galaxy
> S2, S3, and S4 have a dock mode, but the S5 does not. Please check
> your phone features to make sure your phone is equipped with dock
> mode.